# Chrome ajax requests are stuck pending

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

If I make around 8 requests one after another, they load fine, but any after that just say "pending."

Here's my basic html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Editing Quiz</title>
    <script src="../assets/js/lib.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#/test">test</a>
      <a href="#/demos/QuizDemo">QuizDemo</a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the relevant portions of my lib.js:

```
function loadPage(e) {
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
    var baseFilename = location.hash.substr(1);
    var url = "/LiquiZ2" + baseFilename + "_ajax.jsp"; // name of dynamic file to run

    var json = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (json.readyState!==4 || json.status!==200)
          return;
      processAJAX(json.responseText);
    }
    json.open("GET", url, true);
    json.send();
}

window.onload = loadPage;
window.onhashchange = loadPage;
```

If I rapidly click "test" and "QuizDemo" one after the other (or wait a few seconds between each click), after 8 requests they stop loading and just enter a pending state. They don't ever recover and any requests made afterwards stall as well.

This works perfectly in firefox, so I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had video elements on the page. Chrome apparently starts loading the videos automatically, but loads them in chunks so they're never finished until you watch the whole video. So when I loaded the new data for the page, the video requests remained in limbo.

To get around this, I made a global list `media` and whenever I created an element that loaded a stream (`audio`, `video`) I would append it to the list. Then whenever I reloaded the page, I would just iterate through `media` and call `media[i].removeAttribute("src")` and then `media[i].load()` which would attempt to reload the stream. Reloading the stream automatically aborts all its previous requests, and if src is not present the load fails silently.